# Image rotation in python is confusing

Tags: python, list

```
def rotate(self, matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]
    for i in range(n):
        matrix[i].reverse()
    return matrix
```

Here is the code for a matrix/image rotation function in Python. This works for all cases and I'm confused as to why. Can someone explain to me why this works, since I cannot seem to find a simple solution online that is also curt and pythonic.

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra? Draw a 2x3 or 5x5 matrix, fill them with the letters a-f (or a-y) and follow your code to see what happens.

Comment: @ToddBurus I got stumped when I tried to figure out how this extended to square examples of varying sizes

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work right for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, if you start with the following matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

In the first nested `for` loop block, it basically transposes the matrix:

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

then reverses each row to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise:

```
[[7, 4, 1],
 [8, 5, 2],
 [9, 6, 3]]
```

As a side note, this would be a much shorter (and possibly faster) way of doing it:

```
def rotate(self, matrix):
    return list(zip(*reversed(matrix)))
```

Which is basically the same, but uses the built-in function `zip` to transpose the matrix and a list comprehension for conciseness. It can also rotate rectangular matrices. The major difference would be that the original code modifies the function argument (`matrix`) performing an in-place rotation, hence having a lower space complexity.

You can similarly implement counter-clockwise rotation:

```
def rotate_ccw(self, matrix):
    return list(reversed(zip(*matrix)))
```

Comment: The original code seems to only "rotate" square matrices, but not MxN. Nice shortened code.

Comment: @ToddBurus Correct. As I mentioned in my answer, my alternative is able to rotate rectangular matrices too, but will return the rotated matrix instead of modifying it in-place.